# How are the joint distribution and dependency related?

Tags: joint-distribution, copula, dependent-variable

Here are some notes about copula functions,

> Copula is a probability model that represents a multivariate uniform distribution, which examines the association or dependence between many variables. Put differently, a copula helps isolate the joint or marginal probabilities of a pair of variables that are enmeshed in a more complex multivariate system. [Reference](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/copula.asp)

And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) says,

> Copulas are used to describe/model the dependence (inter-correlation) between random variables.

But I don't completely understand how the copula and dependency are related to each other. Informally, we say two variables are dependent if one variable change, the other change accordingly but joint probability is the likelihood that two or more events will happen at the same time. But it is not clear to me that why *copula characterizes the model's dependence structure.*

Comment: I think you have a fundamental issue with the probabilistic notion of *dependence*. Dependence between variables $X$ and $Y$ does not mean that a change in the realisation of the variable $X$ implies a deterministic change in the realisation of the variable $X$, but rather that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ will be modified (by this change).

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for the insight! Yes It was exactly what confused me. I hadn't thought about dependency in the context of probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$, suppose you know their distribution functions $F_X$ and $F_Y$. However, these tell you nothing about their dependence, namely, the conditional distributions $F_{Y|X}$ and $F_{X|Y}$. Given $F_X$ and $F_Y$, copula produces the joint distribution function $F_{X,Y}$. From $F_{X,Y}$ and $F_{X}$ you can derive the conditional distribution $F_{Y|X}$ (and from $F_{X,Y}$ and $F_{Y}$ you can derive $F_{X|Y}$), and the latter tells you how $Y$ depends on / varies with $X$ (and vice versa).

(This is not about deterministic dependence where given $X=x$ we know exactly what value $y$ the variable $Y$ takes. We only know the distribution of values of $Y$ given $X=x$, and that distribution varies with the values of $X$. Xi'an provides a helpful comment on probabilistic dependence above on which this note is based.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just want to check: Does $F_{Y|X}$ tell how $Y$ varies with $X$?

Comment: @Etemon, yes, exactly.